# why my webtile keeps fetching error when I use a static json file as datasource?

Tags: microsoft-band

The json looks like:

```
{
     "status": "ok",
     "posts": [{
        "id": 0,
        "title": "test"
     }]
}
```

and the response header:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 16 Sep 2015 00:47:36 GMT
ETag:"39-51fd2713995fd"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Wed, 16 Sep 2015 00:33:06 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.6.13
```

while my tile keeps showing 'something wrong with the data'

my manifest.json:

https://jsonblob.com/55f8c4a9e4b01190df38996b

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the manifest of the WebTile to share? If so I could take a look at it and see if I can find the problem.

The most likely problem is that the text bindings are incorrectly configured.

Comment: and I follow http://developer.microsoftband.com/WebTile/ChooseLayout to create my tile

Comment: What platform are your testing the WebTile on? I will be able to try it out tomorrow on all three and see if this is a platform specific issue.

Comment: Initial review of your manifest looks ok. I wonder if it is because your 3 and 4 entries in the content URL have no trans_title field?

Comment: android Microsoft Health Version 1.3.10625.4

Comment: And if some entries have no binding field, there will be fetch error.

Comment: I found some potential problems: 1. complete fields 2. using map(hash/object) seems to be better than array 3. pretty formatted json

Comment: Just o follow up, Is it ok now?